# Two RAM sticks into a four DIMM slot motherboard... which slots?

Tags: memory, ddr

I am installing two 8GB DDR4 DIMMs into this motherboard:

[Gigabyte B150M-D3H-GSM](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5541)

There are four DIMM slots of alternating colors, labeled in the following order:

- DDR4_1 (gray)
- DDR4_3 (black)
- DDR4_2 (gray)
- DDR4_4 (black)

The motherboard has dual channel DDR4, so I want to make sure there's one DIMM in each channel, right?

Comment: The different colour slots are there specifically to answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the page you linked to, go to `CPU / Memory / Support & Downloads`, select [the manual](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5541#manual).

On the fourth page it shows the numbering of the DIMM slots. Use the slots numbered 1 and 2.

For more details, see the page 11 (section 1-4).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was a very polite RTFM. I was confused because the manual in the box was one page--I didn't realize there was a full manual on the Gigabyte website. I looked--honest!

Comment: Heh. I actually felt bad about not posting the actual content. Someone has edited it in though.  As for a full manual: Did you geta CD or DVD with the motherboard? That probably has a PDF of the manual.

Comment: I did get CD. Didn't look, but it probably has the manual.